# What kind of metric would a spherical region of space have outside it , if it contains uniformly distributed black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

Would the metric outside the spherical region be related mathematically to the schwarzschild metric?

Comment: Eventually the uniformly distributed black holes would coalesce into one big black hole.  After that the exterior solution would be Schwarzschild (or Kerr.)

Comment: I doubt there is analytical solution to this.

Comment: The BH won't be static by themselves, they will have some motion, associated with outgoing gravitational radiation. Since you are considering spherical distribution, I guess the metric outside this group of BHs can be modelled approximately by Robinson-Trautman metric

Answer (score 1):

In terms of analytical solutions, only an instantaneous, time-symmetry moment field configuration for of a system of many black holes can be found and given.

These are exact solutions of the initial value problem of GR, but they do not describe the whole time evolution of such a system. For this, a numerical simulation has to be performed.

N-black hole initial data problem's solutions are called Brill-Lindquist initial data and Misner initial data.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5660886/

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically asks for the metric outside of the spherical region. This is presumably a vacuum, and so by [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) it would indeed by the Schwarzschild metric, assuming that the black holes are considered stationary (e.g. if their relative motions are relatively insignificant).